# AWSSDK .Net S3 invalid characters in key value of an object with "PutObjectRequest"

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket. I am using Amazon SDK AWSSDK.

Almost every file is uploaded , but some file names have mixed languages and characters like;
"ms.video.downloader/music/youtube/даша астафьева & nikita - синее платье.mp3"

my code is

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest();
try {
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file.LocalPath, FileMode.Open)) {
        request.WithBucketName(_bucketName)
                .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead).WithMetaData(metadata)
                .WithKey(file.S3Path).InputStream = fileStream;
        client.PutObject(request);
    }
} catch (Exception) {

}
```

and

file.S3Path value contains "ms.video.downloader/music/youtube/даша астафьева & nikita - синее платье.mp3", this key causes exception.

How can I handle this? I read that Key values are unicode, so there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the key relates directly to a url, certain characters (& in your case) need to be escaped properly.

General guidelines:

> **[Naming Buckets and Keys](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1904)**
>
> Though buckets can be named with any alpha-numeric character,
>   following some simple naming rules will ensure that you can reference
>   your bucket using the convention .s3.amazonaws.com.
>
> 1. Use 3 to 63 characters.
> 2. Use only lower case letters (at least one), numbers, '.' and '-'. Don't start or end the bucket name with '.' and don't follow or
>      precede a '.' with a '-'. Keys can be named with any properly encoded
>      UTF-8 character.
> 3. Literal '+' characters should always be URL encoded.

Comment: But this is not the bucket name, this is the key for an object. Does same rules apply to key values of objects as well?

Comment: Yes, it applies to keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was setting metadata with invalid characters. There was nothing worng with key values for the object. But metadata was tricky.